# How to maintain workflow step state information in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create simple workflow using Azure Logic App. My workflow is a sequential workflow having only 3 steps. For each of the steps there can be multiple approvers. My question is, how do i maintain workflow state information at each step? Say for example, my workflow should not proceed to next step until my current step is approved. Also, once the current step is complete, my workflow should reside in the next step until that step is either approved/rejected.

I believe, I will have to create multiple triggers along with conditions to verify if the current step is approved or rejected so as to go to the next step. Any good sample on defining such simple sequential workflow in Azure Logic App would be helpful. I referred many Logic App samples, but i couldn't found any good logic app sample which demonstrate how to solve complex multi-step workflow which we used to build using Windows Workflow Foundation.

[Note: We are leveraging SQL DB for maintaining worlfow step information]

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use actions of type webhook to accompolish this. Once a webhook actions starts executing, it will issue a subscribe request with a unique callback URI that can be invoked to resume the action. You would need an external service to maintain the state and instruct the logic app when to resume (i.e. invoke the callback URI).

You can find more information on webhook actions and triggers here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/connectors-native-webhook/